# adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() not working when I update ArrayList

Tags: android, android-listview

I have seen a lot of post about this case but I don't find a solution for me.  I use `SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener` and this is my code in `onRefresh()` method. This doesn't work.

```
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {

            Aviso aviso = new Aviso();
            aviso.setTitle("MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM");
            aviso.setDescription("Deskribapena");
            aviso.setPubDate("Wed, 19 Mar 2016 12:40:00 GMT");
            aviso.setDcDate("2016-03-19T12:40:00Z");

            avisosList.add(aviso);  

            swipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        }, 2000);
```

But if I create new adapter and set in the ListView the result is good

```
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {

            Aviso aviso = new Aviso();
            aviso.setTitle("MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM");
            aviso.setDescription("Deskribapena");
            aviso.setPubDate("Wed, 19 Mar 2016 12:40:00 GMT");
            aviso.setDcDate("2016-03-19T12:40:00Z");

            avisosList.add(aviso);


                   adapter = new AvisosEnListaAdapter(getActivity(), avisosList);
                   lv.setAdapter(adapter);

               swipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
        }
        }, 2000);
```

Adapter code:

```
public class AvisosEnListaAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    protected Activity activity;
    protected ArrayList<Aviso> items;

    //Constructor
    public AvisosEnListaAdapter (Activity activity, ArrayList<Aviso> items){
        this.activity = activity;
        this.items = items;
    }

    public AvisosEnListaAdapter(ArrayList<Aviso> items) {
        this.items = items;     // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return items.get(position).get_Id();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View v = convertView;

        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inf.inflate(R.layout.custom_avisosenlista, null);
        }

        //Create Aviso object
        Aviso aviso = items.get(position);

        //write title
        TextView title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.custom_avisosenlista_tv_title_aviso);

        //Fuente
                Typeface fontTitulo = Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(), "fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf");

                //Setter fuente
                title.setTypeface(fontTitulo);
        title.setText(aviso.getTitle());

        //write data
        TextView tvData = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.custom_avisosenlista_tv_data_aviso);
        Typeface fontData = Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(), "fonts/OpenSans-LightItalic.ttf");

                //Setter fuente
                tvData.setTypeface(fontData);
            tvData.setText(aviso.getFechaParaPublicar());

        return v;
    }



}
```

Where is the problem?

Well, exist a little problem that the element appear in the last position and I want to appear in the first position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have one way

Create refresh method in your `Adapter` like

```
 public void refresh(ArrayList<Aviso> itemsw) {
    this.items = itemsw;     
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Now you just called this method from your `Activity`

```
Aviso aviso = new Aviso();
aviso.setTitle("MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM");
aviso.setDescription("Deskribapena");
aviso.setPubDate("Wed, 19 Mar 2016 12:40:00 GMT");
aviso.setDcDate("2016-03-19T12:40:00Z");
avisosList.add(aviso);
adapter.refresh(avisosList);
```

EDIT:
To add the element at a particular location, use a different overload method for arraylist

instead of

```
avisosList.add(aviso);
```

use

```
avisosList.add(index, aviso); //Indes is the position where you want your item to appear
```

Comment: It's work, but Why the new element appear in the last position? I need to scrolling to look it.

Comment: @aldakur Just change  `return items.get(items.size() - 1 - position);` in `getItem(...)` in your `Adapter` (Add item at first position)

Comment: I'm sorry but `return items.get(items.size() - 1 - position);` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Any time in your Activity/Fragment do you do any avisosList = new ArrayList(); or something like that to re-add the new items? If so, you must know that a new object is being created, so it doesn't link to the adapter list object, so that's why it is failing to update.

You can only do the "new ArrayList()" only once when managing the adapter, and then to change the content of the List everytime you want to change the adapter, and then, of course, to call to notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 0):

Reload the list elements into you adapter.

```
Eg:
adapter.setListItems(avisosList); 
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the addition of the element in the adapter instead of adding an element to the list from which the adapter is created

```
public class AvisosEnListaAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
   protected Activity activity;
   protected ArrayList<Aviso> items;
   ........
   public void addItem(Aviso item){
       items.add(item);
   }
}
```

then

```
adapter.addItem(aviso);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```